# How to use Pandas apply() on a dataframe by using lambda functions?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10
idx = np.linspace(0, 1, N)

labels = ["a", "b", "c"]
values = np.stack((np.random.rand(N), np.random.rand(N), np.random.rand(N))).transpose()

df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=labels, data=values)
```

Assume now that I want to subtract the value `3` from column `"a"` and the value `5` from column `"b"`.

I can easily achieve that through the following:

```
cols = labels[0:2]
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].subtract([3, 5])
```

However, if I use the following:

```
df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda x: x.subtract([3, 5]))
```

I get a `ValueError: Lengths must be equal`.

If I use

```
df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda x: x.subtract(3))
```

It works but it subtracts `3` from both the columns specified in `cols`.

Given the generality of the method `apply()`, I would like to understand how to use it when the type of `x` in the `lambda function` used in the `apply()` method is a `dataframe` and I want to do different things in different columns.

I am searching for the less verbose way, I am aware that I can do it through a for loop by iterating on `cols`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axis=1` for processing per rows, but it is slowier like vectorized first solution:

```
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda x: x.subtract([3, 5]), axis=1)
```

You can check how it working with `print`:

```
#each Series has 2 values by rows
df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda x: print (x), axis=1)

#each Series has all values of columns
df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda x: print (x))
```

Comment: It worked! But what do you mean with "it is slower"? Slower with respect to what? :)

Comment: @Barzi2001 - Slowier like `df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].subtract([3, 5])`

Comment: Ok, so what is the fastest then? :)

Comment: @Barzi2001 - Fastest is use `df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].subtract([3, 5])`, because apply are loops under the hood